# Get the path of the downloads folder in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file, download

I'm building a script that will save an image from the web to the user's computer. This is what I've learned, so far:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/my-image.jpg';
$img = '/my/folder/my-image.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Is this the right way to do this? If so, how would I get the path to, say, the downloads folder, in the user's machine?

Comment: Is this script meant to be run on the user's computer, or on your web server?

Comment: `file_put_contents` is used to write files on your server, not the user's computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The Downloads folder is a browser-specific location that only the user has control of. The file will download to the folder that is specified by the user.

Use `readfile` along with `header` to force a Save As... dialog to appear.

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/server/path/to/image.jpg');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! So what do I put for the outgoing path? "/"?

Comment: You don't specify a destination path when downloading a file.

Answer (score 1):

> If so, how would I get the path to, say, the downloads folder, in the user's machine?

You can't store contents on the user's computer this way, only on your local server.

You need to serve the file as a download, which the user can then "Save as..." in their browser.