# Find path of file downloaded via php

Tags: php

I'm currently attempting to find the source path to a file which I am downloading from it. I'm not sure how to explain, but I'm going to try my best.

I send a `GET` request to our server, it looks like: `GET /en/download.php?pod_id=2138`. From here the server proceeds to reply:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=neatgv4m7a1pdorjqmoo76s151; path=/  
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=2015-09-06-2.wav  
Connection: close  
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
Content-Type: Application/octet-stream
```

I captured this of course using WireShark. Next comes the full WAV file, but I'll spare us that.

I'm curious whether I can get the path to `2015-09-06-2.wav` so that I might be able to download the file that way. Is this possible or will the server not permit me to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for is possible.  A properly written server should never expose a local path.

Comment: I've decided to delete my answer and vote close this question. Trying to access a file directly that the server owner doesn't allow you to in the first place, feels like you're trying to circumvent some sort of pay system or worse, access a bad file uploaded by yourself.

Comment: I assure you icecub I am doing nothing malicious. I merely automate a process of downloading a daily .wav file that is provided for free.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your intentions are honorable or not. Someone with less honorable intentions will visit this question in the future and use the information to do things (s)he shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download.php will provide the file for security reasons. So if secured enough its not possible to directly access the file or folder directly. The direct access might be blocked using .htaccess or it might be placed where the public can't access directly or the file(blob) might be fetched directly on request from the database on request by the download.php

If its not protected from direct access the file is somewhere in the server in some folder. You could access if you find it. but there is no way to find it without a clue. browse through you might find.

Most likely direct access would be unavailable if its provided by the php file in that way.

Answer (score 0):

In short: not possible:

The Downloads folder is a browser-specific location that only the user has control of. The file will download to the folder that is specified by the user.

Use readfile along with header to force a Save As... dialog to appear.

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/server/path/to/image.jpg');
?>
```

[Get the path of the downloads folder in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094686/get-the-path-of-the-downloads-folder-in-php)

Comment: I'm not sure that I've explained myself well enough. I am working on the client machine, trying to download a file from the server. I attempting to find the path where the file is stored on the server so that I could download the file directly from there (instead of via `download.php` ).